# SharePoint 2013 Installation 3tier farm

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I am installing SharePoint 2013 Farm in 3 tier environment. At which Stage do I need to install the cumulative updates of SharePoint Server. and What's the Process?

Answer (score 1):

The CU can be applied immediately after installing the SharePoint binaries. I'd recommend it, that way when you create your farm, there are no further patches you would need to apply.

Comment: Thanks a lot...can u help with procedure of CU? I appreciate your quick response.

Comment: Install SharePoint, install CU. That's about it. Or you can slipstream the CU by using uber-cu-name.exe /extract:C:\sharepointInstallbits\updates. That will let you install SharePoint and automatically apply the bits during the install process.

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following way as per my experince.

- Install sharePoint binaries on all sharepoint servers
- Install the Latest CU (what ever you want) on all sharepoint servers
- Run the config wizard start from the server where you want host the central admin.

Comment: thanks a lot... I have got three files i.e ubersrv_1CU, ubersrv_2 CU, ubersrv2013-kb3114726-fullfile-x64-glb CU, which file do I need to install in SharePoint Standard Server 2013 SP1... I appreciate your response.

Comment: All 3 files must be in same folder, then run the exe file...which is  ubersrv2013-kb3114726-fullfile-x64-glb

Comment: i have done the above procedure... but I am getting "the installation of this package failed.". My license is SharePoint 2013 Standard Server  SP1 . The CU files for Enterprise and Standard is same right? if can you give link for Standard version CU.

Comment: no both are same...when it says installation of package failed? try to reboot the server and retry again.